# REGEXEXTRACT - Error when trying to get a phone number from sting

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am wondering if someone can help me get this formula right in google spreadsheets.

After a 2 week event I do get a spreadsheet with more that 2000 rows of comments which include phone numbers here and there. I am trying to extract the phone numbers from those strings.

example string: call at 228-219-4241 after

formula: =IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(V133,"^(?(?:\d{3}))?[-.]?(?:\d{3})[-.]?(?:\d{4})$"),"NOT FOUND!!!")

and I do  get "NOT FOUND!!!!

[image from gsheet... NOT FOUND!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVeMN.jpg)

But it works only in this case..

[just the number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYML9.jpg)

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is too complicated and your restricting it to a rule that says the number is the first thing in the string, change to this:

```
=iferror(regexextract(A1,"\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}"))
```

In your example the '^' sign means beginning of the line and '$' means the end so your saying the first thing in your string will always be 3 numbers and the last will always be 4